# Pascal : Delphi Length String Command Error

Tags: delphi, string, pascal

I'm writing a section of code to read in CSV files and parse information out of them (currently I just have the beginning part of the code which will read in the headers at the beginning of the file. When I try to compile this code I'm receiving an error on the line which takes the length of the line from file.

The error I'm recieving is: [Error] MCLRandomizer.pas(***): Missing operator or semicolon

```
while not EOF(csvFile) do begin
        i :=0;
        ReadLn(csvFile, line);
        if lineOne = true then begin
          length := Length(line);               //error here
          while length > 0 do begin
            dx := Pos(',', line);
            buffer := Copy(line, 0, dx-1);
            headers[i] := buffer;
            line := Copy(line, dx+1, length);   
            length := Length(line);             //error here
          end;
          lineOne := false;
        end;
      end;
```

Comment: What kind of error and how does the declaration of "length" and "line" look like?

Comment: Is there any chance you'll receive quoted fields or escaped commas in your csv file?  If so, the above approach wont work.  You're generally better off iterating every character using a TFileStream.

Answer (score 11):

Pascal makes no difference between length and Length ... they both are LENGTH

Rename the variable, it messes up the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. Wow, wasn't really expecting that to be it.

Comment: I don't agree that it is a weak point. I find it much easier to read code, less error prone, etc.

Comment: Weak points? I consider case-sensitivity to be one of the weakest points of C/C++/Java/etc. Why should "myvar" be different from "Myvar" and "myVar"?

Comment: @David: Yes, it most certainly is case-insensitive. But I am not quite sure I'd call that "one of its weak points". After all, surely it wouldn't be a good idea to have a function named `Length` and a variable named `length` in the same block of code, even if that would work, technically? Still I *do* find strange capitalization ugly, e.g. `BEGIN` and `Begin` instead of `begin`. Thus, if the language enforced standard capitalization, code would probably *look* better on average because everyone would write it the same way.

Comment: @Graham Case is important. Every decent programmer uses it. Every decent Pascal programmer writes MyVar every time and doesn't occasionaly use myvar. Anything that is significant in the mind of the programmer should also be significant to the compiler. That's why I prefer Python significant indentation over other block delimiters.

Comment: Wirth considered it a weak point (I assume) since his later languages were case-sensitive. They also removed the stupid single/compound statement botch.

Comment: David: there is a difference between a bit of casing manually added for readability, and enforcing it to the point that two differently cased identifiers are different. That is (IMHO) several bridges too far. And afaik Wirth was interested in this to make keywords stand out, more than casing itself. Nowadays syntax highlighting performs this task

Comment: I do agree on the compound block bit. The M2 way is way better. I also like the end-of-procedure/function/method with added identifier, that way a missing END never goes beyond a function block.

Comment: @Marco nobody would define myvar and MyVar. Just think how much software is written with case-sensitive languages. I contend that the defenders of case-insensitivity in this thread are basing their opinion on biased viewpoints. This discussion would be better balanced by a bunch of C/C++/Objective-C/D/Java/C#/Python/AndSoOn developers.

Comment: @Marco M2 blocks are great. I didn't get on with the BEGIN IF WHILE shouting though!

Comment: I believe that case-sensitivity is a serious design flaw in a programming language.

Comment: The old joke was always that Wirth did it because they you'd have twice the number of one-letter identifiers :-)

Comment: David: the point is that I think Wirth never intended identifier usage with difference casings. He just wanted to let keywords stand out in a period without syntax highlighters, and when most programmers used lowercase. Judging this by todays realities is revisionism IMHO.  .... And the whole point to start is that there is a difference between using case, and enforcing it.

Answer (score 3):

FTR: If you **really, really** want you can write

```
length := System.Length(line);
```

(assuming `length` is an Integer). I agree with the other posters that that would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

A solution I developed to read a csv file into a record structure (actually an array of records structures) is

```
program read_file_into_array_of_records;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, StrUtils;



type
    Tscore = record
                name : string [25];
                marks : integer;
              end;

var
    input_file: TextFile;
    file_record : string[100];
    score : array [0..3] of Tscore;
    index : integer;



// function that returns all text up to a comma or the end of the line
function get_value() : string;
var
    comma_pos: integer;
    value: string[100];
begin


    comma_pos := Pos(',', file_record);

    // if comma found cut out all text up to it
    if comma_pos <> 0 then
    begin


        value := leftstr(file_record, comma_pos - 1);


        delete(file_record, 1, comma_pos);
    end
    else
    begin

        // no comma found so just take everything that remains
        value := file_record;
    end;

    get_value := value;


end;


// procedure to fill one record by breaking up the comma separated values
procedure fill_record (index: integer);
begin

    // call the function get_value as many times as needed to get
    // each comma separated value
    score[index].name := get_value();
    score[index].marks := strtoint(get_value());
end;


// procedure to fill array with contents of csv file
procedure fill_array ();
begin


    index := 0;



    while not EoF(input_file) do
    begin


        readln(input_file, file_record);


        fill_record (index);


        index := index + 1;
    end;


end;


// procedure to display contents of array
procedure display_array ();
begin



    for index := 0 to 3 do
    begin


        writeln(score[index].name, ' got ', score[index].marks, ' marks' );
    end;

    readln;

end;


// main prog

begin

    assignfile(input_file, 'scores.csv');

    reset(input_file);

    fill_array ();

    closefile(input_file);

    display_array();

end.
```

the contents of scores.csv:

> james,31
>   jane,23
>   toby,34
>   ruth,40

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, Pascal strings at 1, not 0. (copy() statement)